# how to disable ubuntu install iso automatically upgrade distribution

Tags: server, upgrade, custom-distributions

I create an ubuntu 14.04 install iso and use cobbler help me to deploy system in my network.
My question is, My install ISO's distibution is 14.04.1，but when cobbler finished system installation, I fond system distribution is upgraded to 14.04.5.
For some reasons, I must keep system distribution to 14.04.1.
Appreciate any help...thanks

Comment: Please check with 'uname -a' which kernel is used (if it is the trusty kernel (3.13 if I remember correctly)  or the xenial kernel 4.4. If the kernel is still 3.13 I think you have the hardware enablement stack of 14.04.1 LTS, even if 'lsb_release -a' announces 14.04.5 LTS. - Or is the problem, that you cannot allow any updating at all?

Comment: See this link http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16410/heads-up-hwe-changes-for-16-04?cb=1

Comment: What is the reason? 14.04.1 is obsolete, updating will bring it up to 14.04.5. Note that the original kernel and xserver versions are not upgraded, unless you opt-in for HWE.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, ubuntu 14.04.1's kernel is 3.13.0-32-generic,and ubuntu 14.04.5 is 4.4.0-38-generic.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, ubuntu 14.04.1's kernel is 3.13.0-32-generic,and ubuntu 14.04.5 is 4.4.0-38-generic. And in my working enviroment, for compatibility reason, I must keep system release to 14.04.1 even if 14.04.1 is obsolete...

Comment: You can easily install the original kernel 14.04 came with, which is STILL SUPPORTED https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Answer (score 0):

In order to install the kernel Ubuntu Trusty came with originally (3.13) which is still supported, according to the **[LTS Enablement Stacks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)** instructions you need to run:

Desktop

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty
```

Server (or if you only want the kernel)

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not about ubuntu's kernel version. It's about ubuntu's distribution version. I need keep it to 14.04.1 not newer version.

Comment: In your comments just mention the kernel, is there something specific you need? Because that doesn't make sense.